# Using ARGF and hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to write a ruby program that contains a method that will convert a single letter amino acid code into it's corresponding amino acid name after reading from ARGF.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def convert
aminos = Hash.new
aminos = {"A" => "alanine", "B" => "aspartate/asparagine", "C" => "cystine"}
output = aminos.values_at()
puts "#{output}"
end

ARGF.each_char do convert
end
```

If I run this program, it does the following:

```
$ ruby amino_acid.rb ABC 
[]
[]
[]
```

When what I want it to do is this:

```
$ ruby amino_acid.rb ABC
alanine
aspartate/asparagine
cystine
```

I am not sure what to put in the parentheses after

```
aminos.values_at
```

or if I am even on the right track?

I think I have to pass a parameter to this method, maybe something like

```
def convert {|k,v| puts "#{v}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good start is to show what you have written that you are having specific problems on, this will allow us to answer specifically.  You may want to read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) resource available.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: You can read the standard input with [gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) but as @vgoff already wrote, you'd need to show specific part of your code you have issue with.

Comment: First read up on Ruby's [ARGF](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/ARGF.html) class. Now do the following in IRB: `File.write('temp.rb','puts ARGV') #=> 9`. 9 characters (`"puts ARGV"`) were written to the file `temp.rb`. You can confirm that with `File.read( 'temp.rb') #=> "puts ARGV"`. Now exit IRB and enter the following from the command line (no quotes): `ruby temp.rb cat dog`. That should cause 
`cat` and `dog` to be printed.  You have told Ruby to execute the code in the file `temp.rb`. (cont..)

Comment: (...cont.)   The code in the file `temp.rb` (the single line `"puts ARGV"`) has access to the array `ARGV` which equals `['temp.rb', 'cat', 'dog']`.  In your problem It seems the line entered at the command line will be something like `ruby temp.rb amino.rb`, where `amino.rb` is a file containing a string of amino acid abbreviations such as `"ABC"`. So, in `temp.rb` `ARGV[1]` will equal a string giving the name of the file you need to read from (`"amino.rb"'). Let's say you read `"ABC"` from that file into a string called `abbrevs`. (cont..)

Comment: (..cont.) Now you can execute (in `temp.rb`) `abbrevs.each_char { |c| <some code> }`, where `<some code>` converts the character `c` to the full name of the amino acid and then prints it. (I presume "output the corresponding amino acid" means to print it.) btw, `File` is a subclass of `IO`.  The class methods `File::write` and `File::read` are actually [IO#write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-write) and [IO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-read).  Good luck!

Comment: Please see above, I edited in the code that I have so far... sorry!

Comment: They key here is ARGF.  That is to read values from a file.  ARGV is to get those arguments you pass in the way you are passing ABC (unless ABC is a file).  The documentation for this is not the simplest to find... [ARGF documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html) specifically look for ARGF which will tell you to look at `$<`.  It is not what you want to use, I think, and causing you some pain.  More info to come...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ARGF` when you are wanting to use `ARGV` based on your example code.

[code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) will give you other avenues for style, etc.  But I think this will get you going.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def convert(value)
  aminos = { 'A' => 'alanine', 'B' => 'aspartate/asparagine', 'C' => 'cystine' }
  aminos[value.upcase]
end

ARGV.to_s.each_char do |string|
  puts convert string
end
```

You could, of course, put that statement inside your method, but really methods should do a very focused thing.  Passing it an argument, rather than it acting on ARGV directly gives it freedom to be used in different ways.  A method should do one thing, generally.  Keeps them easier to maintain.